# Virtualize a physical SIM Card to a Android phone

Tags: android, virtualization, sim-card

I carry two phones around with me all the time.

Is there a way I can virtualize my second SIM card to my Android phone?

When I virtualize, my first SIM card is still plugged into my Android phone but my second SIM card is no longer plugged into any phones, but it is virtualized on my Android phone.
When I get call or messages from my second SIM, my Android phone will receive it cause my second SIM card is virtual.

So is there any solution available out there like that?

Answer (score 1):

In, short no. Even if you can clone the card, related functionality is the baseband software (AKA radio firmware, etc.) and proprietary Android drivers, so you can't modify them to use your virtual card. You might be able to find a phone that has two SIM slots, but I haven't heard of one with Android.

Answer (score 0):

The virtualization might require to copy the SIM card which is very hard to do.

And right now this technique is kind of tricky, you can look into this scholar article [Virtualisation of a SIM-Card using Trusted Computing](http://sit.sit.fraunhofer.de/smv/publications/download/virtualisation-sim-card-final.pdf)

Comment: @Chris the link is working and it's not an internal one. If you still can not get access to it, try this [Google Search link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sim+card+virtualization&aq=0&oq=SIM+card+virtuali&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)